# В MAMP не запускается Apache сервер, но работает MySQL в 10й винде

Tags: apache, mamp

Я пробовал менять порты c 80 на другие; удалил скайп, который бы мог занимать 80й потр; в MAMP/conf/apache/httpd комментировал "LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so". Ничего не помогает, что делать?

Comment: Такая же проблема. Удалось решить?

Comment: К сожалению нет((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mamp -> Prefernces -> port -> set mamp ports to default
и там же во вкладке php нужно выставить более раннюю версию 7.2.14

Answer (score 0):

C:\MAMP\conf\apache\httpd.conf  запустить 
Далее закомментить строку: 
Loadmodule perl_module modules/mod_per_so
И перезапустить Apache